# I have a type error when i run this command

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The code is work fine until I wrote the methods `df.describe()` and `df.info()` all the code run ok except the two methods.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")
print("The first 5 rows of the dataframe") 
df.head(5)
df.info()
```

I upgrade numpy and pandas to the latest  version
numpy version is 1.21.4
and pandas 0.25.1

What is the best solution to this problem? I have the same error when I run this code also: d`f.describe()` the prblem is in `df.info()` and `df.describe()` they give me an error every time I run it as follow

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) in ----> 1 df.describe()

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in describe(self, percentiles, include, exclude) 10263 elif (include is None) and (exclude is None): 10264 # when some numerics are found, keep only numerics
    
    10265 data = self.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) 10266 if len(data.columns) == 0: 10267 data = self
    
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in select_dtypes(self, include, exclude) 3425 # the "union" of the logic of case 1 and case 2: 3426 # we get the included and excluded, and return their logical and -> 3427 include_these = Series(not bool(include), index=self.columns) 3428 exclude_these = Series(not bool(exclude), index=self.columns) 3429
    
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in init(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath) 309 data = data.copy() 310 else: --> 311 data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True) 312 313 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
    
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure) 710 value = maybe_cast_to_datetime(value, dtype) 711 --> 712 subarr = construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(value, len(index), dtype) 713 714 else:
    
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(value, length, dtype) 1231 value = ensure_str(value) 1232 -> 1233 subarr = np.empty(length, dtype=dtype) 1234 subarr.fill(value) 1235
```

I can't understand what is the main problem I try to update numpy and pandas and I see related answers on this problem but I didn't  see any solutions.

Comment: "pandas 0.25.1": that version is "ancient". Your upgrade either failed, or you didn't enter the correct version. Please double check your Pandas version.

Comment: your traceback isn't complete.  You haven't shown the actual error message yet.

Comment: The problem is  jupyter dosen't recognize the methods describe and info

Comment: The traceback tells me that it is running the `describe` method.  The error lies deep in `describe`, where it's trying to construct a Series.  `describe` actually returns and displays a new dataframe.  You/we can't find  "solution" without first identifying the problem.  The first guess that there's a mismatch between the pandas version and the numpy is likely.  The full error message may confirm that.